# Nginx error 403 on laravel app - Centos 7

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I Got this annoying 403 forbidden error on my nginx server running on centos 7

you can check for yourself
http://zargold.com

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  zargold.com;
    root         /home/zargol/public_html/public;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    #location / {
    #    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    #}

location ~ \.php$ {
    #try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    root /home/zargol/public_html/public;
}
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

I've been working on this for days it doesn't get repaired!

Note: I've used instructions in [here](https://medium.com/@clasense4/install-latest-laravel-using-nginx-php-fpm-on-centos-7-8ef12c149f87)

**update**:
something seriously strange happend right now.
I have two domains set on this vps ip address and the other one comes up with a different error(502 Bad Gateway)
http://zar7.com

Comment: Have you checked file ownership and permissions?

Comment: Yes the premissions are on 777

Comment: That root is correct? (Asking because zargold/zargol)

Comment: You commented the `location / { }` block but didn't comment the `try_files` inside, try commenting that out too or uncomment the whole block

Comment: @kerbholz yeah it's ok

Comment: @teeyo Tried that too right now. no change

Comment: try adding a index.html file

Comment: @PraneethNidarshan didn't work either!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined an `index` directive, so `nginx` is using the default value of `index index.html`.

If there is no `index.html` file in the root directory, `nginx` will return a 403 response.

For Laravel you should probably use:

```
index index.php;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for more.

Comment: You have two `root` statements. You will get a 404 response if they are not identical.

Comment: aren't they identical?

Comment: beside, I still get the error considering that i removed second one